# Difficult displaying data with linechart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im trying to learn how to use chart.js but I cant get it to work with all those exemples out there. I have a table in mysql with temperature-data and dates.
Managed to format it with json_encode in getdata.php, like this (small example);

```
[
  {
    "date":"2018-04-01 00:00:02",
    "temp":"1.2"
  },
  {
    "date":"2018-04-01 01:00:50",
    "temp":"1.0"
  }
]
```

I have been struggling with it for a week now, trying all sorts of tutorials and examples with no luck :(
Can someone please show me how to display this data as a simple linechart???
Anyone know of a example with similar data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it works now...
After some google I found out that I had to execute the script after the canvas-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<!-- Importing Chart.js and creating our canvas to draw the line. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Our sample data.
var myDATA = [
  {
    "date":"2018-04-01 00:00:02",
    "temp":"1.2"
  },
  {
    "date":"2018-04-01 01:00:50",
    "temp":"1.0"
  }
];
// Grab the canvas.
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
// Paint to canvas a line chart with some options.
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [myDATA[0].date, myDATA[1].date],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'TEMPERATURES',
            data: [myDATA[0].temp, myDATA[1].temp]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8h6qumq/10/

Comment: works perfect in fiddle, but cant get it to work on my server. I've put the script in a .js-file and inserted a link like;
<script type="text/javascript" src="linegraph.js"></script>

Is this wrong thinking?

Comment: might add that the page is all blank

Comment: checking the console gives me this;
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at linegraph.js:13